# Install fuse debian 8 jessie

Tags: linux, udev, fuse

I'm on debian 8 jessie with a 4.2.3 kernel. I can't seem to get fuse installed and working. When I install fuse with `sudo apt-get install fuse` I get `MAKEDEV not installed, skipping device node creation.` Also when I do `sudo modprobe fuse` I end up with `modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found.` I tried installing `makedev` but that didn't work because I already have `udev`. That just got me `/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by enabling FUSE_FS module in kernel compile .config

Answer (score 1):

On Debian jessie x86_64:

```
apt-get remove makedev
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install makedev fuse`.

Alternatively, `sudo apt-get install udev fuse` should work because the `Depends:` line for package `fuse` has `udev | makedev`.

Comment: I already tried installing `makedev` as stated in my original post.

Comment: package `makedev` only conflicts with package `udev` (<= 0.024-7), which is ancient.  any later version should be OK.

Comment: Well I tried it and it conflicted. It aborted `makedev` because it detected `udev`

Comment: what does `lsmod | grep fuse` and `modinfo fuse` say?  add them to your answer, not in a comment.